# Parsing the date with timezone MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

In a table say **testTable** we are storing date-time as `varchar` in following format

```
Tue May 09 15:16:54 IST 2017
```

I am trying to write a query which gives me all records between two dates using `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the date in `varchar` format to `datetime`. However below query is failing with `Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

```
SELECT * FROM test12.testTable a WHERE a.timestamp BETWEEN (STR_TO_DATE('Tue May 09 17:26:11 IST 2017', '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Z %Y'), 
  STR_TO_DATE('Wed May 10 20:17:11 IST 2017', '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Z %Y'));
```

Could you suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: Store dates as dates. Why make life complicated for yourself?

Comment: Agree, I know that should be stored as date only but I am using a third party library to populate audit events, unfortunately it is not providing way to decide structure of schema.

Comment: timestamp is varchar, right? So...

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah I can see that now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your dates are stored in this weird way, you want to use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function on the column, not on the string you provide.

```
SELECT * FROM test12.testTable a 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(a.timestamp, '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Z %Y') 
BETWEEN '2017-05-09 17:26:11' AND '2017-05-10 20:17:11';
```

Comment: When your dates are stored in this weird way, you want to have a friendly chat with the designer.

Comment: Converting column values to date is returning null values !! Anything wrong with parsing format? `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(a.timestamp, '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Z %Y') FROM test12.testTable a;` is returning all null records.

Comment: I just copied from you :) What is `%Z?` That doesn't exist: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format Might be the cause. When it's always `IST` in the string, write it literally so in the `STR_TO_DATE()`.